# Bash Script -exec syntax

Tags: git, bash, githooks, uglifyjs

I’m trying to make a Git hook bash script that minifies my JavaScript code. 
So far I have come up with this, it just prints the minified JavaScript when I run the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
find js/ -type f -maxdepth 3 -name \*.js -exec uglifyjs {} +
exit
```

I’m not sure how to give the `uglifyjs` any commands and what the output filename should be.

In the terminal it would be:

```
uglifyjs -o js/app.js js/app.js
```

So I’m not sure how to reference the file names etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say:

```
find js/ -type f -maxdepth 3 -name \*.js -exec uglifyjs -o {} {} \;
```

instead.  Note the `;` instead of the `+` after the command.